# The code I have for a JFrame works in one package but not another

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to generate a simple JFrame that is titled Target Gallery.
In the target gallery package the only result I get is a message that it ran successfully.
I made another package with the same code and the JFrame appears as it should.

This is the code that does not produce the JFrame.

```
 package targetgallery;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Andelis
 */
public class timerFrame extends JFrame{

    public timerFrame()
    {
    setSize(new Dimension (300,300));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Target Gallery");
    setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main (String args[]){
        timerFrame time = new timerFrame();

    }

}
```

This is the code that generates the JFrame.

```
       package test;

    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    /**
     *
     * @author Andelis
     */
    public class Test extends JFrame{

        public Test()
        {
        setSize(new Dimension (300,300));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Target Gallery");
        setVisible(true);
        }


        public static void main (String args[]){
            Test time = new Test();

        }

    }
```

[This is the result of the first code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNbCk.png)

[This is the result of the second code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvYar.png)

Comment: Are you working with an IDE? Can you post a Screenshot of your opened projects and the console saying it ran succesfuly? Most probably you have set another project as the main one. Right clic on `timerFrame` class file and then clic on "Run this file" or Run as "Java application" any of them or similar options. Also, please follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) i.e. class names start with a capital letter (as you did with "Test" class).

Comment: Btw I won't get notified if you edit your post, so when you add this information or comment with the info I'm asking you, can you please notify me with: @ Frakcool (Without the space between the `@` and my name)

Comment: @Frakcool here are the screen  shots of the results.

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above your first's code file you have another file with a main method, called `Targetgallery`.

Delete this class (`Targetgallery`) if you're not using it or remove the main method there (I bet it's empty).

Another option would be right clic on `timerFrame` file then clic on `run this file`.

Comment: @AndrewArcher if my answer solved your question please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so if anyone has the same problem they can check it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to compile the code before you run it.
do you work with Eclipse?